# XAML Icon color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, drawingbrush

I have ResourceDicionaryIcon where i store icons like DrawingBrush. And i want to change Brush color from {DynamicResource GreyBrush} to something that will allow me to choose color in control template button (Same color as text).

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="icoEdit" Stretch="Uniform">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource GreyBrush}" Geometry="F1 M 4.95279,30.227L 11.737,37.0113L 37.5279,11.2205L 30.7437,4.43622L 4.95279,30.227 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource GreyBrush}" Geometry="F1 M 31.7877,3.39215L 38.572,10.1764L 41.9641,6.78424L 35.1798,0L 31.7877,3.39215 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource GreyBrush}" Geometry="F1 M 10.6276,38.096L 0,41.9641L 3.86807,31.3365L 10.6276,38.096 Z "/>
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Actually i dislpay icon in Canvas like background. But thats not allow me to choose color. Is there any better solution how can i do this?

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" (...) Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
```

**EDIT:**

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" (...)>
                        (...)

                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" (...) Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" (...) Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" (...)>

                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid> 
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Button x:Name="Button" 
Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" 
Foreground="#FF434341" 
Background="{DynamicResource icoEdit}"  
Content="BUTTON TEXT" (...)/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should put your `Binding` backward like this:

```
<GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}" Geometry="F1 M 4.95279,30.227L 11.737,37.0113L 37.5279,11.2205L 30.7437,4.43622L 4.95279,30.227 Z "/>
```

Here I my binding `Brush` to upper/parent element

I don't have Visual Studio right now to check this colution. Please correct me if I wrong